# Alterar background color de uma row de uma table utilizando checkbox

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Estou tentando alterar a cor de uma `row` quando um `checkbox` é selecionado, mas quando selecionou apenas um, o `table` inteira é alterada a cor, o check permanece apenas no selecionado, mas a cor é alterada em todas as `row`s.

Estou utilizando o Angular o Angular 9 e o Angular Material.

HTML:

```
<ng-container  [matColumnDef]="tableData" *ngFor="let tableData of objectKeys(columnHeader)">
        <div *ngIf="columnHeader[tableData] === 'select'">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            <mat-checkbox color="primary"
              (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null "
              #item (click)="check(!item.checked)"
              [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
              [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
              [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
            </mat-checkbox>
          </th>
          <div *ngIf="columnHeader[tableData] === 'select'">
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <mat-checkbox color="primary"
                #item [checked]="selection.isSelected(element)"
                (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(element) : null" [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(element)"
                (click)="check(!item.checked)"
                >
              </mat-checkbox>
            </td>
          </div>
        </div>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="objectKeys(columnHeader)"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: objectKeys(columnHeader);" [ngClass]="{'mat-row': rowChecked}"></tr>
```

css:

```
.mat-row {
  background: #2F80ED;
}
```

Comment: Você poderia mostrar um exemplo visual?

Comment: Não entendi. Uma imagem por exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Na met-cell dentro da sua tabela utilize um [ngClass] ou um [ngStyle] que pode resolver o seu problema, como por exemplo:

```
[ngClass]="{'row-selected': item.checked === true}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Foi resolvido declarando uma variável no TS:
`selection = new SelectionModel<any>(true, []);`

No HTML, a validação fica assim:
`[ngClass]="{'item-selected': selection.isSelected(element)}"`